# Read a big matrix out of ram from several files using bigmemory library

Tags: r, out-of-memory, rbind

I have a matrix out of ram memory that is in several files in my hard disk. By using the bigmemory package, I can operate on my matrix without loading completely on RAM, but the problem is how to read the big.matrix from several files?

This is just a simple example code.

```
library (bigmemory)
library (biganalytics)
library (bigtabulate)

x <- read.big.matrix(c("2001.csv", "2002.csv", "2003.csv"), type ="integer", header =TRUE , backingfile ="airline.bin", descriptorfile ="airline.desc", extraCols ="Age")
acindices <- bigsplit (x, c('TailNum', "Year"))
acStart <- sapply ( acindices , function (i) edit(x[i, c('Year','Month')]))
```

It doesn't work because read.big.matrix expects only a file. Is there a solution without loading all table on ram?

Comment: please, help! that is just I need to finish a project